# My code rotates a bmp picture correctly but only if the number of pixels is a muliple of 4... can anyone see whats wrong?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

It only works when the width and height are multiples of four, whats missing? 2x2... 4x4....16x16... 400x400... all work but not if its just a random .bmp pic.

```
 void rotate90(Image& image)
    {
        Pixel * tempPixel = new Pixel[(image.infoHeader.biWidth * image.infoHeader.biHeight)];
        int tempWidth = image.infoHeader.biWidth;
        image.infoHeader.biWidth = image.infoHeader.biHeight;
        image.infoHeader.biHeight = tempWidth;
        for(int r = 0; r < image.infoHeader.biHeight; r ++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < image.infoHeader.biWidth; c++)
            {

                int f = c+(r*image.infoHeader.biWidth);
                int t = (image.infoHeader.biHeight-r-1) + (image.infoHeader.biWidth*c);
                tempPixel[f]=image.pixels[t];
            }
        }

        delete[] image.pixels;
        image.pixels=tempPixel;
    }
```

Comment: What does the rotated image look like when it doesn't work? If it looks *skewed*, it could be related to the stride of the bitmap.

Comment: it looks like there are alot of garbage bits inbetween all the good pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner for loop should probably be

```
int f = c+(r*image.infoHeader.biHeight);
int t = (image.infoHeader.biWidth-r-1) + (image.infoHeader.biHeight*c);
tempPixel[f]=image.pixels[t];
```

To calculate the index for a flat array of a pixel at `[x,y]`, you need to use `i=y+Y*x` or `i=x+X*y` if `Y` and `X` are the width and height, respectively.