# Image Processing (vector subscript out of range)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have spent probably too many hours looking for tutorials on image processing (WITHOUT the use of external libraries) with no real success. If anyone knows any good tutorials that can be found that can help in this way, I'd really appreciate that.

I am pretty new to coding (this is my first year in college), and the assignment our professor is asking for requires original code to transform 24-bit bitmap images.

I found a question in StackExchange that shows rotation of an image without use of external libraries:

[My code rotates a bmp picture correctly but only if the number of pixels is a muliple of 4... can anyone see whats wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426890/my-code-rotates-a-bmp-picture-correctly-but-only-if-the-number-of-pixels-is-a-mu)

Using this code (with the starter project we were given and I had to build upon), I was able to create this code:

Byte is defined as a typedef of unsigned chars.

```
void BMPImage::RotateImage() 
{

vector<byte> newBMP(m_BIH.biWidth * m_BIH.biHeight);
long newHeight = m_BIH.biWidth;         /* Preserving the original width */
m_BIH.biWidth  = m_BIH.biHeight;        /* Setting the width as the height*/
m_BIH.biHeight = newHeight;         /* Using the value of the original width, we set it as the new height */

for (int r = 0; r < m_BIH.biHeight; r++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < m_BIH.biWidth; c++)
    {
        long y = c + (r*m_BIH.biHeight);
        long x = c + (r*m_BIH.biWidth - r - 1) + (m_BIH.biHeight*c);
        newBMP[y] = m_ImageData[x];
    }
}

m_ImageData = newBMP;
}
```

This code doesn't show any red squigglies, but when I try to execute the rotation, I get a vector subscript out of range error message pop-up. I've only used vectors in one assignment before, so I don't know where the issue is. Help please!

I think the issue might be here:

```
m_ImageData = newBMP;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume your newBMP has width = 1 and height = 2 then

```
vector<byte> newBMP(m_BIH.biWidth * m_BIH.biHeight);
```

would be an array of size 2 with valid indexrange [0 1]. Your index calculation

```
long y = c + (r*m_BIH.biHeight);
```

would be 2 for c = 0 and r = 1. But 2 is not a valid index for your vector and with

```
newBMP[y] = ...
```

you access an element that is not part of the vector. Your index x would be -1 for this example.

Comment: So...I would want -1 the final number to account for the first element being 0 instead of 1 and the vector size actually seeming to be one less because it starts with 0... Then...`long y = (c + (r*m_BIH.biHeight)) -1` ?